# Spring 3.2: @WebAppConfiguration breaks existing @Transactional tests

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-roo

Greetings.
I have a Roo generated web app. I want to test my controller. So am using spring-test-3.2.
    Using STS 3.2.
 Embedded Derby for testing.
    The test suite fails when the controller test is wedged between two integration tests - breaks the integration test following it. If I @Ignore the controller test, suite runs fine. This integration test has both Roo generated and my own test methods.
    I searched around a lot - but cannot reason for this behaviour. I suspected Transactions not rolling back correctly, but that seems all fine (logs are fine). 
    I just have just one empty controller test method. I think for some reason my @ContextConfiguration is the issue...

Integration test before:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/META-INF/spring /applicationContext*.xml")
@Transactional
public class CompanyServiceImplTest {
```

Controller Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(value = {
    "file:src/main/resources/META-INF/sprin/applicationContext.xml",
    "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml" })
@Transactional
```

Integration test after (This breaks)

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml")
@Transactional
@RooIntegrationTest(entity = Status.class)
public class StatusIntegrationTest {
```

Would be grateful for any pointers...

--- cheerio atul

Comment: _The test suite fails_, fails how?

Comment: The breaking test method assumes

Comment: Apologies - missed the error - The breaking test method assumes the database is clean (as the class is marked @Transactional) - and creates **4 objects** - next it calls the active record _countAll..._ method. When test is run stand alone, this works fine. However, if the suite (as above) is run, it suddenly reports **19 objects** - Where are these 15 extra objects coming from - is the @Transactional semantics somehow screwed up?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably caused by https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6121

A workaround that worked for me was to make all unit tests use the same application context by adding @WebAppConfiguration to all unit tests, and ensuring they all have the same @ContextConfiguration.

You look like you are using Spring Roo. To avoid editing all existing unit tests, you could  make a copy of your webmvc-config.xml for your tests, renaming/moving it to match the applicationContext*.xml pattern.

Adding @WebAppConfiguration annotation to existing tests can be done using an aspect:

```
package com.foo.bar;

import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;

privileged aspect WebAppConfigurationAspect {
   declare @type: com.foo.bar..*Test: @WebAppConfiguration;
}
```